# How do I clear command prompt before each netstat refresh?

Tags: windows, netstat

How do I clear the command prompt screen before printing out netstat information when using a refresh interval?

I've been using `netstat -anp TCP | Find "5000"` to view information for a specific port. I've been attempting to add a refresh interval, but also clear the screen every time it's refreshed. The closest attempt I've made is:

```
netstat 1 -anp TCP | (cls & Find "5000")
```

With the above, I'm trying to run `cls`, followed by `Find "5000"` after every netstat refresh. However, it only runs `cls` once, and `Find "5000"` each time. Is something like this possible with netstat?

Comment: This can be accomplished by creating a small batch script. Would that work for you? Also, what operating system are you using?

Comment: @and31415, I'm looking for a non batch solution for now. I'm using Windows 7, and it would be used on a couple version of Windows server. If something _similar_ to what I provided isn't possible (and short), a batch script would work.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're trying to depend on Netstat's internal Interval system it's what's causing you grief, as Netstat doesn't really "end" each time.

You could break it up a bit, remove the Netstat interval, and make it into a looping batch file.

This batch file should work on all versions of Windows (2000+ anyway)

```
@echo off
:GoAgain
cls
netstat -anp TCP | Find "5000"
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
goto GoAgain
```

The `ping` to localhost line is used to create an approx. 1 second pause before looping (on Vista+ you could use the `timeout` command instead to make it more accurate if you'd like).

To stop it, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to break out of the loop.